Access Order Subscription Details via Shopify REST API
I have a Shopify live app.
I'm importing the client store orders. For one client they sells products including subscription beauty products. The subscription is handled through https://app.smartrr.com. I need to retrieve the subscription details for these orders using the Shopify REST API.
Could someone please guide me on how to access subscription information for orders through the REST API?
Are there specific endpoints or fields I should be aware of for fetching these details? If it is not available in REST API how to get it through GraphQL or other methods?
